# Strange behavior of referrals on Area 51

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, commitment-phase, referrals

I advertised the Hinduism Proposal on Area 51 using [this referral link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29980/hinduism?referrer=O61EDbZrbsvPxdCuGp6-8Q2). This is what I see in my Area 51 reputation point history:

[image]

However, [the page itself](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29980/hinduism) shows that [I have referred four people, and there have been a total of five people committing after me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKl9D.png).

In summary:

- I have received reputation for four referrals
- I have two referrals which I haven't received reputation for
- The page lists four referrals under my name
- The page lists five people who have joined after I have

None of this matches up. Reputation points aside, there are two referrals unaccounted for. If the fifth guy who joined was a referral of mine, then (a) it should show up as my referral, and (b) there still is one referral unaccounted for.

Comment: Just a guess: someone followed but then backed?

Comment: @tohecz: hmm. possible, though we ought to have an "unfollow" rep event as well. Also, I find it unlikely that this happened _twice_

Comment: I haven't read well and missed the 2nd one, sorry. My another guess was "referrals are transitive but assigned rep is not", only to find that non of your "referee" has any "referee", so it cannot be the case.

Comment: @tohecz: 6 referrals, 5 new users. Forget who is "marked" as a referral, we are missing a user here.

Comment: Hence the name, Area 51. Get it?

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday, someone committed as a referral, then de-committed. The same happened today. That's why on your reputation summary, the fifth referral yesterday, and the last one today, are shown as having no points. The four commitments that stuck, are shown on your other area51 screen-cap.

The most recent commitment on that screencap was not referred by you.

So there's no inconsistency.

5 recent commitments to Hinduism have stuck: 4 (jokerdino, unsung, pareg, naresh sharma) were referred by you. One (Ethereal) was not.

5 commitments to Hinduism were referred by you yesterday, 4 (jokerdino, unsung, pareg, naresh sharma) stuck. One (user ID not listed) from yesterday did not stick. And one user from today did not stick.

You got 20 points for those 4 that stuck (4 x 5 =  20)

Comment: _two_ didn't stick (I have a total of 6 events in my history). Which I find slightly unlikely. (Also, the system should be clearer about this)

Comment: Ah yes - just saw the one from today, as well as the 5  from yesterday.